# JQuery detach vs remove

Tags: jquery

It is written in jQuery documentation that remove() on a selector removes all the events associated with it. But in the following code after remove function is called, alert associated with onclick on #this is not removed.. What am I missing here?

Code:

```
<div style="width:100%; min-height:100px; background-color:yellow;" id="add"  onclick="remove()">
    <ul id="remove" style="width:100%; background-color:purple; padding:4vh;">
        <li>
            <div id="this" style="width:100%; height:5vh; background-color:red;" onclick=alert("Clicked")>
                    Abc
            </div>
            <div style="width:100%; height:5vh; background-color:blue;">
                    XYZ
            </div>
            <div style="width:100%; height:5vh; background-color:orange;">
                    LMN
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
var t = 0;
var sp;
function remove(){
    if(t % 2 == 0){
        sp = $("#remove").remove();
        t++;
    }
    else{
        $("#add").append(sp);
        t++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### .remove() (jquery docs)

> Similar to .empty(), the .remove() method takes elements out of the
>   DOM. Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself, as well
>   as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, all
>   bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed.
>   To remove the elements without removing data and events, use .detach()
>   instead.

#### onClick

**HTML attribute** should be avoided as It makes the markup bigger and less readable. Concerns of content/structure and behavior are not well-separated, making a bug harder to find.

#### your code

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    var t = 0;
    var sp;
    function remove(){
        if(t % 2 == 0){
            sp = $("#remove").remove();
            t++;
        }
        else{
            $("#add").append(sp);
            t++;
        }
    }

    $('#add').on('click', function(event) {
        remove();
    });

    $('#this').on('click', function(event) {
        alert('clicked');
    });
    
});
```

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  
  <div style="width:100%; min-height:100px; background-color:yellow;" id="add">
   <ul id="remove" style="width:100%; background-color:purple; padding:4vh;">
    <li>
     <div id="this" style="width:100%; height:5vh; background-color:red;">
      Abc
     </div>
     <div style="width:100%; height:5vh; background-color:blue;">
      XYZ
     </div>
     <div style="width:100%; height:5vh; background-color:orange;">
      LMN
     </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`onclick` attribute is not the same as `.click()` in jQuery. When appending `sp`, all the tags are back to DOM with their attributes. In fact, that handler is not not removed. It is reattached after appending. This will not happen if you use jQuery's `.click()` except of `onclick`

**EDIT**

For your example:

```
$("#this").click(function() { console.log(this); alert("Some text"); });
```

No need to use `onclick` in this case. This event will be detached after `#this` element is deleted. Also, this approach doesn't work on newly created elements.

If you need to handle some event (not only click) on dynamically generated elements you may use this approach:

```
$("body").on("#this", "click", click(function() { console.log(this); alert("Some text"); });
```

More information:

https://api.jquery.com/click/

https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thank you very much for great explanation